# Trying to find and click link in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a page that contains the following line of html

```
<td><span><a onClick="setSummaryClasses(3)">Reality</a></span></td>
```

Copied from the FF Source panel. I try to click the anchor with

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Reality').click()
```

and I get a

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Reality"}'
```

What am I missing?

I have both

```
driver.set_script_timeout(10)
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
```

active.

Comment: What selenium driver are you using?

Answer (score 3):

1. Ensure the link isn't inside any kind of frames. Otherwise please use [`switch_to_frame`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=frame#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_frame) first.
2. When you match link text, bear in mind it does exact match, so if you have messy whitespaces, please try [`find_element_by_partial_link_text`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=link_text#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_partial_link_text)

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Reality').click()
   ```
3. Changing locators might also be helpful.

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onClick='setSummaryClasses(3)']").click()
   ```

Comment: And ensure the current window in Selenium is the window you think it is :).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user1177636, I realised that, when a click opens a window, in the LIVE situation the new window becomes the current "top" window, while in Selenium it doesn't.

Therefore I needed to

```
driver.switch_to_window('Chat23')
```

before looking for the element.

Hope this helps somebody.